# What "people who care about us" means in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, pronouns

I'm non-native English speaker. I'm reading a book about the Simpsons right now. I read this sentence a million times and still don't understand what exactly the author wants to say.

> The Simpsons, already twenty years old and still beloved, will be
>   watched and enjoyed for as long as there are **people who care about us,
>   our culture, and our time**.

I looked up "care" in the dictionary, but still don't understand the proposal. I assume the author wants to say that as long as there are people who have respect for yourself, proud of their culture and who value their time, the Simpsons will always be with us. I understand the part 'who care about us' as people who have respect for yourself. I don't know, maybe I'm wrong. I need your help.

[The last paragraph of the book](https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/zs12/).

Comment: I haven't read the book. However, I think it is from the pov of the simpson's author so the "us" in "people who care about us" means: "people who care about the producers and writers of the whole simpson story".

Comment: By the way, that book was written by fan. Link: https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/zs12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**us** there probably refers to Americans.

*The Simpsons* satirizes American life and culture.  There is a lot not to be proud of in each episode.

P.S. OP comments  "I still don't understand what means 'Americans, who care about Americans'".

In the phrase "people who care about us, our culture, and our time" the word **us** refers to America, that is, to *the nation and its people*, and the word "people" refers to any human beings, Americans or not.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Replica Foxtrot: You're welcome to your doubts, but "as long as there are people who have respect for yourself, proud of their culture and who value their time" is a total fabrication on your part. You get all of that from the verb "care"?

Comment: Earlier in the piece the author speaks about "popular interest". That phrase better explains what "care" means there than your understanding which involves a sense of national or cultural pride.  People don't feel *pride* when they watch the show, as it ridicules American popular culture in a very funny way.

Comment: @ReplicaFoxtrot To be absolutely sure you have to ask the author, Charlie Sweatpants. He looks American to me. I think that Tᴚoɯɐuo is right. "Us" refers to Americans, people who care about (United States) Americans, their culture and the time depicted in the show (late 1990 - today) from their point of view.

Comment: I'm sorry, but, unfortunately I still don't understand what means 'Americans, who care about Americans'. It looks like a literal transition. You want to say that Americans take care of yourself ?

Comment: @Replica Foxtrot: I will add a P.S. but in this latest comment you're glossing "people" as "Americans" but your question was about the word "us", not about the word "people", on the one hand, and on the other, you're equating the two, "people" and "us", but they don't necessarily refer to  the same thing.